# Creating 'posts page' loop based on the page itself

Tags: wp-query, loop, archives

The setting `Settings -> Reading -> Posts Page` is set to my 'News' page, and the loop for the `home.php` template is populated with posts... great.

However I want to also be able to create another loop (even with `WP_Query` if needed) of which contains the actual page of which I've specified my `Posts Page` to be.

Whenever I try and and instantiate this loop it returns loads of posts instead of the page I've asked for, here's my code, compare the args with the request SQL:

```
<?php

    $page = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'page_id' => 39));
    print_r($page);

    // REQUEST: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10

?>
```

You can see the request SQL query is wrong, I'm guessing because I've set the page as the `Posts Page` it's preventing me from using it within a loop.

Is there a way around this? I want to use the title, content and custom fields within the `home.php` template.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected page for posts by the following code:

```
$page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
```

Then, get the requested post by:

```
$post = get_post( $page_for_posts );
```

And, get the data you need:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title );
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $single);
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've got the first two parts, I really need it to overwrite the loop. I tried using `setup_postdata` but that fails too... looks like WP doesn't want me to do this ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by, "*I really need it to overwrite the loop*"?

Comment: I worded that badly, as my 'News' page is the 'Posts page', the loop it initially populate to display a range of posts, I need to be create a new loop just for the page, thus overwriting the global `$post` object. So functions like `the_title()` will work without having to pass an ID.

Comment: Hmm, if `setup_postdata` really doesn't work, I wonder if there is a workaround for this. Perhaps you can create an if-statement in your page?

Comment: "*I need to be create a new loop just for the page, thus overwriting the global $post object. So functions like the_title() will work without having to pass an ID*" - Are you wanting your custom loop *before* or *after* the main query loop? What code have you tried? What happened *unexpectedly*, or *didn't happen as expected*?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using `home.php`, that you output the main query loop as per normal, and that you want to output a secondary loop using the `$post` information for the `page_for_posts` page:

1. Define your custom query [using **`WP_Query()`** and appropriate post parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters).
2. Target the normal post object for the page, via `get_option( 'page_for_posts' )
3. Output your custom query loop
4. Reset `$post`, using [**`wp_reset_postdata()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).
5. Output the main query loop

For example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Blog posts index template file: home.php
 */

get_header();

 // Let's output your custom loop *first*
$home_query_args = array(
    'page_id' => get_option( 'page_for_posts' )
);
$home_query = new WP_Query( $home_query_args );

if ( $home_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $home_query->have_posts() ) : $home_query->the_post();
    // Output your custom query as per normal,
    // using all normal post template tags,
    // such as the_title(), the_content(), the_permalink(), etc.
endwhile; endif;

// IMPORTANT: Reset $post
wp_reset_postdata();

 // Now output the main loop query
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // Normal loop output here,
    // using all normal post template tags
endwhile; endif;

get_footer();
```

The secret sauce here is **`wp_reset_postdata()`**. It resets the `$post` global to the main loop query.